# How to solve pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch using docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

It worked after I followed the instructions at computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-on-debian-linux but I tried to run `python manage.py dbbackup` again today and it does not work.

I don't understand why it says `No such file or directory: '/root/usr/bin/pg_dump'` when the path matches the path from `find . -name pg_dump`

shell to postgres container

```
root@6d515751e154:/# pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1)
root@6d515751e154:/# find . -name pg_dump
./usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump
./usr/bin/pg_dump
```

base.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT"),
    }
}

DBBACKUP_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DBBACKUP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {'location': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../backups')}
DBBACKUP_CONNECTORS = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT"),
        # "DUMP_CMD": os.path.join( # Tried both of these
        #     os.environ['HOME'],
        #     "usr",
        #     "bin",
        #     "pg_dump"
        #     )
        "DUMP_CMD": os.path.join( # Tried both of these
            os.environ['HOME'],
            "usr",
            "lib",
            "postgresql",
            "13",
            "bin",
            "pg_dump"
            )
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    wagtail:
        build: .
        container_name: wagtail
        command: python /code/mysite/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.dev
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - .env/.dev
        depends_on:
            - pgdb
        networks:
            - wagtailnet
    
    pgdb:
        image: postgres:13
        container_name: pgdb
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        env_file:
            - .env/.dev_db
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        networks:
            - wagtailnet

volumes:
    pgdata:

networks:
    wagtailnet:
```

Traceback 1:

```
Backing Up Database: postgres
CommandConnectorError: Error running:  /root/usr/bin/pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/bin/pg_dump'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 118, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle  
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 74, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 78, in create_dump
    dump = self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 38, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 156, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 146, in run_command
    process = Popen(cmd, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=full_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/bin/pg_dump'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute      
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv    
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 118, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle  
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 74, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 78, in create_dump
    dump = self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 38, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 156, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(
dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  /root/usr/bin/pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/bin/pg_dump'
```

Traceback 2:

```
Backing Up Database: postgres
CommandConnectorError: Error running:  /root/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 118, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle  
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 74, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 78, in create_dump
    dump = self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 38, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 156, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 146, in run_command
    process = Popen(cmd, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=full_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute      
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv    
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 118, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle  
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 74, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 78, in create_dump
    dump = self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 38, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 156, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(
dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  /root/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump'
```

---

### Update above

I am running a django server(image python:3.8.2-slim-buster) and a postgresql(image postgres:13) database on separate docker containers. I am trying to use django-dbbackup to back up data and ran into this error.

```
# python manage.py dbbackup
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
account.EmailAddress: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the AccountConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
account.EmailConfirmation: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the AccountConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
socialaccount.SocialAccount: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the SocialAccountConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
socialaccount.SocialApp: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the SocialAccountConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
socialaccount.SocialToken: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the SocialAccountConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Backing Up Database: postgres
CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres
pg_dump: server version: 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1); pg_dump version: 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1)
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 118, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 74, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 78, in create_dump
    dump = self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 38, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 150, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 118, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 61, in handle
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 74, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 78, in create_dump
    dump = self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 38, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 150, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(
dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres
pg_dump: server version: 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1); pg_dump version: 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1)
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

After searching for answers, I tried to update postgresql-client but it says I already have the newest version.

```
root@528fdf5ac614:/code/mysite# apt-get install postgresql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-client is already the newest version (11+200+deb10u4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

So I don't know how to proceed. Should I downgrade the database container using postgres:11.12 docker image? That means data will be lost?

Also, why does the error say dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump  --host=pgdb --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean postgres ?
I have set the password in base.py like so:

base.py settings

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT"),
    }
}

DBBACKUP_CONNECTORS = {
    "default": {
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST"),
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the postgres repository to get postgresql-client-13. See e.g. https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-on-debian-linux/

Comment: There could be two pg_dump binaries on your system. Try to locate them, and call the correct one by using an absolute path.

Comment: No, you are *not* using the latest version of PostgreSQL on the client side. That's the problem.

Comment: Thanks @aciniglio. Following the instructions at https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-on-debian-linux/ until `apt -y install postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13` worked. I managed to run the backup. Oddly, running `pg_dump --version` still returns `pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1)`, which still seems to be different from server version: 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1).

Answer (score -1):

Your error is self-explanatory

```
pg_dump: server version: 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1); pg_dump version: 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1)
```

You should find psql as well as pg_dump for this installation under /postgres/bin/. This is the pg_dump you want to use. You can validate the version of pg_dump using

```
pg_dump --version
```

django-dbbackup allows you to specify the connector it uses to create the backup. In particular, it allows you to specify the dump command (DUMP_CMD). To specify the connector, add the following block to your settings.py:

```
import os  # if not yet imported
DBBACKUP_CONNECTORS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'xxx',
        'PORT': 'xxx',
        'DUMP_CMD': os.path.join(
            os.environ["HOME"],
            'xxx',
            'bin',
            'pg_dump'
            )
        }
    }
```

Make desired changes as per your installation and user.

Comment: I tried what you said but got `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump'`. Is the path not correct because I am using Docker? Please see update above. Thanks